# Why do neutron scattering lengths vary seemingly randomly with atomic number?

Tags: neutrons

I'm a bit unclear as to what determines neutron scattering lengths, and hence why they can vary so much even between adjacent elements like Fe and Co. I gather it's related to resonant scattering, but I would be very grateful for an account (ideally not purely mathematical!) of how and why.

Comment: Isn't it surprising that chemical properties vary so much between adjacent elements like Xe and Cs?

Comment: Honestly, I would say no, because I can readily explain that by referring to atomic orbitals, whereas neutron scattering is a nuclear rather than electronic property. I don't think saying "Gosh, all chemical properties can vary significantly" is terrifically meaningful. I am aware that the variation is not random, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: Well, nuclear properties also vary pretty significantly between neighboring elements. Indeed, these changes are unrelated to chemical properties.